# Prevent trailing spaces during insert?

Tags: postgresql

I have this INSERT statement and there seems to be trailing spaces at the end of the `acct_desc` fields. I'd like to know how to prevent trailing spaces from occurring during my insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO dwh.attribution_summary
SELECT d.adic,
       d.ucic,
       b.acct_type_desc as acct_desc,
       a.begin_mo_balance as opening_balance,
       c.date,
      'fic' as userid
FROM  fic.dim_members d 
JOIN  fic.fact_deposits a ON d.ucic = a.ucic 
JOIN  fic.dim_date c ON a.date_id = c.date_id 
JOIN  fic.dim_acct_type b ON a.acct_type_id = b.acct_type_id
WHERE c.date::timestamp = current_date - INTERVAL '1 days';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the PostgreSQL `trim()` function. There is [`trim()`, `rtrim()` and `ltrim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL).
To trim *trailing spaces*:

```
...
rtrim(b.acct_type_desc) as acct_desc,
...
```

If `acct_type_desc` is not of type [`text` or `varchar`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), cast it to text first:

```
...
rtrim(b.acct_type_desc::text) as acct_desc,
...
```

If `acct_type_desc` is of type `char(n)`, casting it to `text` removes trailing spaces automatically, no `trim()` necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what others have said, add a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to that column, so if one forgets to pass the `rtrim()` function inside the INSERT statement, the check constraint won't.

For example, check trailing spaces (in the end) of string:

```
ALTER TABLE dwh.attribution_summary 
ADD CONSTRAINT tcc_attribution_summary_trim
CHECK (rtrim(acct_type_desc) = acct_type_desc);
```

Another example, check for leading and trailing spaces, and consecutive white spaces in string middle):

```
ALTER TABLE dwh.attribution_summary 
ADD CONSTRAINT tcc_attribution_summary_whitespace
CHECK (btrim(regexp_replace(acct_type_desc, '\s+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) = acct_type_desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `acct_desc`?

- If it is CHAR(n), then the DBMS has no choice but to add spaces at the end; the SQL Standard requires that.
- If it is VARCHAR(n), then the DBMS won't add spaces at the end.
- If PostgresSQL supported them, the national variants of the types (NCHAR, NVARCHAR) would behave the same as the corresponding non-national variant does.

Comment: There is no NCHAR or NVARCHAR in PostgreSQL

Comment: the column type was varchar() but i realized the problem was that the table i was pulling from had those extra spaces in them. I used the other answer's solution to fix my problem. Thank you for your insight!